# Missing operand after 'by' operator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I used:-

```
ds.Tables(0).Compute("sum(Quantity)", "group by ORI_No")
```

to group and sum Quantity 
then
it is showing error as:

```
Missing operand after 'by' operator
```

Comment: Similar post, solved using [LinQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/111761/DataTable-compute-with-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter, `filter`, determines which rows are used in the expression. .The grouping cannot be performed in `Compute`. I suggest you to use LinQ for the grouping.